# AJAX Control Toolkit - PasswordStrength with CreateUserWizard

Tags: asp.net, ajax, passwords, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to implement a PasswordStrength control with my user registration page, but from what I can find it seems as if it will only work with a regular textbox, but I'm using a CreateUserWizard control for user registration. Is there any way to implement the control I want with a CreateUserWizard or would I need to change the implementation to use a regular textbox control?

Comment: You change the wizard to render template, so you can see the controls, and add it inside and near the password textbox.

Comment: How can I convert without starting from scratch? I only see options for  StartNavigationTemplate, StepNavigationTemplate, FinishNavigationTemplate, and CustomNavigationTemplate

Comment: Think I may have figured it out -- thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Then I make it an answer to not stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

To been able to connect the PasswordStrength control with the password text box, you need to render as template the wizard registration page so the controls be visible.

After that just place the PasswordStrength control near the password box, and inside the template and just correctly setup it. You can not place it outside the template because will fail to find the control to connect.